# At what height should a stair handrail be?

Tags: safety, stairs, railing

I am almost dne replacing the steps to my front porch.  It is 5 steps so I definitly need a handrail, but I don't know exactly how high to make it.  I have some posts that should be plenty tall but I can attach the handrail at any point along the post.  I assume there is some standard height from the stair tread that is usualy used in the US.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard is usually 34" to 38". Check your local building codes - apparently some cities specify exactly 36".

The [International Residential Code](http://www.arcways.com/pdfs/IRC2006.pdf) covers just about everything you could want to know about stair standards.

Comment: Good reference, but the link isn't working... (I still want to do something different with my basement stairs to reduce the head-banging risk at the bottom.)